# Warum müssen transitive Verben im Passiv nicht ergänzt werden?

Tags: verb, grammaticality, passive

Ein transitives Verb im Aktiv muss ergänzt werden, sonst ist der Satz ungrammatikalisch, z.B. ist "er schlug" grammatikalisch falsch. "Er schlug jemanden" oder "er schlug um sich" ist hingegen grammatikalisch korrekt. Im Passiv ist das nicht so, z.B. ist "er wurde geschlagen" grammatikalisch korrekt.

Liege ich falsch mit meinen Annahmen bzgl. Grammatikaliät? Gibt es dafür einen technischen Terminus und/oder eine Erklärung? Ist das in anderen Sprachen auch so?

Answer (score 3):

Das Verb im Passiv *ist* in dem Sinne ergänzt, dass das Objekt des transitiven Verbs zum Subjekt im passiv wird. Das Subjekt des ursprünglichen Satzes im Aktiv, *kann* in der Passivkonstruktion mit der Präposition "von" (+ Dativ) stehen.

Deswegen können intransitive Verben nicht das "normale" Passiv bilden – es gibt kein Objekt das zum Subjekt des Satzes im Passiv werden könnte.
Es gibt allerdings die Form des unpersönlichen Passivs (wie das Beispiel aus Alazons Kommentar: "Hier wird diskutiert!". Bei dieser besonderen Konstruktion ensteht ein Satz ohne Subjekt.

Das ist keine Besonderheit von Deutsch sondern in sehr vielen Sprachen so (insofern nicht in allen, da nicht alle Sprachen ein Passiv besitzen und nicht überall transitive und intransitive Verben im selben Sinne existieren).

Die Frage warum transitive Verben ein Akkusativobjekt verlangen, ist etwas zirkulär: Transitive Verben gerade so definiert. Man kann nicht abschließend Begründen warum, es ist einfach ein Teil der gewachsenen deutschen Grammatik, dass es Verben gibt, die ein Akkusativobjekt verlangen. Falls das konkrete Objekt für eine Aussage irrelevant ist, kann diese Rolle natürlich durch "Platzhalter" wie "jemand" übernommen werden. Es gibt hier also zwei Ebenen: Die Grammatikalische und die Semantische. Dass ein transitives Verb ein Akkusativobjekt verlangt, ist eine Regel der Grammatik.

Oft gibt es eine Bedeutungsnuance bei Verben die sowohl transitiv als auch intransitiv verwendet werden können; dann hat der Satz mit "Platzhalter" und der ohne eine andere Bedeutung; und deswegen kann man den "Platzhalter" nicht einfach weglassen. Zum Beispiel:

- Ich höre jemanden.
- Ich höre.

Der erste Satz (hören transitiv verwendet) bedeutet dass man die Laute die eine Person verursacht mit dem Gehörsinn wahrnimmt. Der zweite Satz (hören intransitiv verwendet) hat diese Bedeutung nicht, er kann die folgenden Bedeutungen haben:

- dass man einen funktionierenden Gehörsinn hat
- (vielleicht etwas umgangsprachlich) dass man gehorcht
- dass manbereit ist akustisch Information zu empfangen (z.B. wenn man ans Telefon geht).

Dass man einen Teil der Information (das Subjekt des Satzes im Aktiv) im Passiv auslassen oder an eine unmarkierte Stelle verschieben kann, ist gerade die Funktion des Passiv. Der Fokus wird statt auf den Aktor auf die Handlung gelegt – entweder weil der Aktor unbekannt oder irrelevant ist, oder weil aus stilistischen Gründen der Patient der Handlung betont werdne soll. Es gibt kein grundlegendes Prinzip, dass ein Satz immer alle möglichen Informationen erhalten muss.

Comment: Natürlich gibt es ein Passiv von intransitiven Verben. Hier wird diskutiert!

Comment: Die Frage ist: Warum muss das Verb durch das Subjekt ergänzt werden, aber nicht durch das Objekt? Der Sachverhalt "A schlug B" wird unvollständig, egal ob man A oder B weglässt: "X schlug B" = "B wurde (von jemandem ) geschlagen" bzw. "A schlug X" = "A schlug (jemanden)".

Comment: Man weiß in beiden Fällen nur 2/3 von dem, was es zu wissen gibt. Abgesehen davon enthält "jemanden" keine Information. Warum ist es dann erforderlich?

Comment: @Alazon Stimmt – sie können das sogenannte unpersönliche Passiv" bilden, wird korrigiert.

Answer (score 1):

Im "werden"-Passiv wird ein Akkusativobjekt, wenn eins da ist, und im "bekommen"-Passiv  wird ein Dativobjekt in ein Subjekt umgewandelt. Ansonsten muss auch das passivierte Verb Objekte haben. Das "bekommen"-Passiv ist weiterhin transitiv: "Er bekommt *den Führerschein* abgenommen." Auch Verben mit zwei Akkusativobjekten behalten eines davon: "Wenn man (1)mich (2)so etwas fragt" --> "Wenn ich (2)*so etwas* gefragt werde".